# querySelectorAll to select only matching elements on top levels

Tags: javascript, css

By top levels, I mean the elements without any matching ancestors, like the `span*` in the following code snippet. How can I select only the `span*`s but not the `span`s?

```
span*
span*   
div
  span*
    span
    span   
  span*
```

Comment: ancestors or parents? from what you are showing it seems parent

Comment: I thought parent is a specific kind/level of ancestor.

Comment: If you are able to edit the HTML can you simply add classes to the key spans and pick them up that way?

Comment: The html is provided by users, what I'm doing is to recursively assign some context to each level of spans, and the next level of spans will inherent the parent's level's context, and so on and so forth. So I will need the parent to take care of their immediate children's context.

Comment: I have a question for the two whoever voted to close my question: do you have any difficulties to understand my question or what?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `I wonder if there's any easy way to ...`, is it not a question? Or does it have to end with a question mark?

Comment: I need one more vote to reopen this question. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way, in selector syntax, to express "An element with no ancestors of the same type" (or even of a specific type).

The obvious approach to this would be to get every element and then recursively check all the ancestors to make sure that none have a matching [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this answer was originally an edit made by the OP to their question; I have merely moved it to its own answer.*

I ended up using TreeWalker:

```
const nodes = [];
const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(rootNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, {
   acceptNode: node => {
      if (node.matches(['span'])) {
         nodes.push(node);
         return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
      }
      nodes.push(node);
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
   }
});
while (treeWalker.nextNode()) { }
return nodes;
```